# Ionic two bar-subheader among each other

Tags: angularjs, ionic-framework

Is it possible to place in Ionic several `bar-subheader` with among each other? In my case, I need only two `bar-subheader` among each other and then the content. It works with one `bar-subheader` but not with two. can someone help me?

Example:

```
<ion-header-bar>
<!--header-->
</ion-header-bar>

<div class="bar bar-subheader">
<!--first sub-header-->
</div>
<!--here is to come the second sub-header-->
<ion-content class="has-subheader">
</ion-content>
```

Answer (score 0):

**div class="bar bar-subheader">
  div class="bar bar-subheader">
    hi
  /div>
   hello
/div>**
Multiple bar sub header's are possible in ionic framework but I didn't understand your question you want a sub-header with in another header